# ASP.Net Report Viewer- SSRS Express - Unable to read data from the transport connection—The connection was closed

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-express

I have some users intermittently receiving this error *'Unable to read data from the transport connection—The connection was closed'* when viewing an ssrs report through the ReportViewer control.

- The user can access the SSRS via web browser and not replicate the error
- On multiple pages reports the first page loads and where it states 'Page 1 of totalPages' this totalPages counts up as the rest of the pages are loaded. Half the time it doesn't display an error but not all pages are loaded.
- We are running SSRS express within a windows application.
- SQL Express installation is a named instance
- When it happens the screen hangs for around 2 minutes
- It occurs on a couple of reports but not others different reports. It's not data amount related, sometimes 50 page reports come through OK and sometimes 2 page reports fail.
- If it fails the user can run the report again and it usually works the next time. Sometimes it takes 3-4 goes.
- Nothing has changed recently, I'm told this was always the case but they never reported it.
- I tried giving the single shared ssrs datasource sa user credentials - no change
- Some reports appear to load OK everytime while others error out or only load a couple of pages.

**What I have tried so far**:

- I cannot replicate this error from our remote client, I just ran 20 successful reports no dramas from within another client installed on the same network. But I can replicate it from the users computer with both my account and their account.
- I cannot see anything relevant in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MyInstance\Reporting Services\LogFiles'.

Thanks in advance for tips on where to look for clues and ways to resolve this issue..

Comment: Maybe a locking issue? Have you checked [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) yet?

Comment: I just checked - all rows report a status of rsSuccess. There's only a couple of users and not very often concurrent usage so it's probably not locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by removing the ReportViewer UI control and we are now creating a pdf of the report using ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render() and opening with Process.Start(). The client only wants a pdf or a print out so we don't need the report viewer as such.

I'm not sure why the connection was closed at times, maybe it's network related as I couldn't replicate on a machine located physically next to the server. Either way this is resolved, onto the next project!